# making two slideshows html

Tags: javascript, html

I can successfully make a slide show in html but im trying to make two and its not working, here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "img/home/residential.gif"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "img/home/1.gif"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "img/home/2.gif"
</script>

<table align="center" width="70%"cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5>

<tr>
    <td rowspan=2 align=center><a href="artistic.html"><figure><img src="logo1.gif" alt="Atristic Impressions" width="400" height="600" name="slide"/><figcaption style="color: #610B21">Artistic Impressions</figure></td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var step=1;
        function slide()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<3)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slide()",5000);
        }
        slide();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "img/barns/1.gif"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "img/barns/2.gif"
    var image3 = new Image()
    image3.src = "img/barns/3.gif"
    var image4 = new Image()
    image4.src = "img/barns/4.gif"
</script>
<td align=center><a href="Barns.html"><figure><img src="img/barns/1.gif" alt="Barn Conversions" width="400" height="300" name="slide"/ ><figcaption style="color: #610B21">Barn Conversions</figure></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image1"+step+".src");
            if(step<3)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",5000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your `<img>`s have the name "slide". You should give them different names so that the browser knows which one to work with. Something like "slide1" and "slide2" should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you are using code that is conflicting with itself. You have defined images at a global level, then redefined them later when setting up the second show. You've also duplicated the step variable, although this may not matter so much if you use the same value. You're also affecting the same image using both slider scripts, so the target on one would need to change. A neater way around this is to use a single function adding some parameters so that you can deal with both sets of images and DOM elements.

something like:-

```
function slide( image_id, image_array) {

     myImage = getElementById(image_id);
     myImage.src = image_array[step];

}
```

Of course, there's a lot more to it than that, and there are plenty of examples of better featured image sliders out there that would be capable of running two separate instances. I'd suggest studying some of those.